# Compare array within objects in an array of the same Mongo document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, comparison-operators

I have a Mongo database with multiple documents and they all contain 2 Items for in store and online locations. The difference will be that attributes within the items object may differ. I am trying to capture all documents that have differing attributes between the object items with the array.

I've tried using $expr and comparing the position of the elements such as "Items.0.Attributes" == "Items.1.Attributes" but had no luck.

```
{
        "ID" : "123456789",
        "Items" : [ 
            {
                "ItemDept" : "softLines",
                "ProductId" : {
                    "Name" : "shirts",
                    "_id" : "12345Shirts"
                },
                "Attributes" : [ "blue","small","mens"],
                "Season" : "Summer"
                "Location":"online"
            }
           , 
             {
                "ItemDept" : "softlines",
                "ProductId" : {
                    "Name" : "shirts",
                    "_id" : "12345Shirts")
                },
                "Attributes" : [ "blue","small","women"],
                "Season" : "Summer"
                "Location":"stores"
             }
            ]
          }
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? ... The full document where the `"Items"` `"Attributes"` are not identical?  Is order or equal number of attributes significant?

Comment: Ideally, the output would return the entire document where the attributes in the item objects do not match. If the number of attributes between the two objects do not match that would be important but the order of the attributes are not not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to `find`/output, here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$not": {
      "$setEquals": [
        {"$first": "$Items.Attributes"},
        {"$last": "$Items.Attributes"}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/26l8MFLWNlb).